# Cloud service monitor changes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I've cloud service and in the cloud service (in azure view )there is tab which is called 
monitor which you can add there settings (like key value),I want to track if some user
did for it some changes and when like **Auditing** ,there is a process which should I invoke to track this changes,with user name and timestamps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, what you're looking for is the `Operation Logs` functionality. It is available in Azure Portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com). Once you login into the portal, click on `MANAGEMENT SERVICES` and then `OPERATION LOGS`. The operation you would want to track is `Change Configuration` (or something like that).

[image]

If you want to track it programmatically, the Service Management API operation you would want to invoke is [`List Subscription Operations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg715318.aspx)

Comment: THanks Gaurav+1!1.Does this table reflect all the changes that user done in the cloud service ?2.this table is fixed or I can ennace it(add additnal fields) ?2.Does this API List Subscription Operations is reflected this table one to one or I can add to it addional fields.

Comment: `Does this table reflect all the changes that user done in the cloud service ?` - If you see the link to `List Subscription Operations` in my answer above, you will see the list of operations tracked. `this table is fixed or I can ennace it(add additnal fields)` - The schema is fixed. You can't add additional fields. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the management portal only makes available a finite list of performance counters for monitoring. And it sounds like perhaps you are trying to add a custom event, which you would not in turn be able to add to that list.

So the broader question then turns to how to log in-app events in a way that I can monitor for. To that end, I'd recommend first looking at [Azure Diagnostics](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/). This gives you a fairly low impact way to capture telemetry about your application. You can then in turn scan the result logs and act on the events you need to capture.

Comment: Thanks Brent,I see that  I need to use DiagnosticMonitor.Start() but where should I put it?and how should I track the monitor config section and where should i see all the diagnostic?